# Durandal - how to know in parent view when child view was composed?

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

In parent view I have simple observable which indicates child view name (string). When this observable changes, child view is composed inside parent view. What I need is an event in parent view after the child view has been composed. I'm not using activator at the moment. I'm guessing that I should replace my simple observable with activator (how to do that so I can use it as simply as I use string observable now) and compositionComplete will be bubbled to parent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `compositionComplete` event is fired after all children composition completed. See the [Durandal documentation,](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/)

> Set compositionComplete to be called back after the entire composition
>   has finished (parents and children included)